# Undesired table spaces in Outlook 2007

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, html-email, outlook-2007

I am coding a newsletter in a table format that ought to be compatible with (mostly) every e-mail client, but Outlook 2007 adds 1px spaces to every image that's in one row with text-elements.

I set `border-collapse: collapse`, `cellpadding="0"` and `cellspacing="0"` on the table and `style="font-size:1px; line-height:0;"` on the TDs but it doesn't work. IMGs are `display:block`. Also setting `valign="bottom"` on the top element and `valign="top"` on the bottom one didn't work.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycpNK/9/ - The red and the green boxes are the ones affected by the spacing. You can reproduce this bug in Outlook 2007.

Does someone know how to get rid of the spaces?

Comment: Could you include some of your html?

Comment: Which is the specific bit of your fiddle where you're having the problem?

Comment: I colored the boxes so you can see where my problem lies. But you can only reproduce it in Outlook2007 on Windows I guess.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the code. I don't have Outlook 2007 so I can't check, sorry I couldn't be more use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, setting `display:block` on the image corrects this behaviour. So try:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" width="100" height="20" style="display:block;" />
```

Another thing to try is to remove all unnecessary whitespace from the cells that you're getting the problems.

---

By 'remove unnecessary whitespace' I mean if you have this:

```
<td> *here there may be several spaces and a return character*
    <img src="foo.gif" />
</td>
```

Replace it with this:

```
<td><img src="foo.gif" /></td> *no unnecessary spaces or returns*
```

It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing your html but this has fixed some of my layout errors.

Comment: I already set display:block on every IMG.
What exactly do you mean by 'remove all unnecessary whitespace'?

Comment: I posted a fiddle in my post.